# Django Validators not working in shell command

Tags: python, django, validation

Django Validators not working in shell command, it works just on Django Forms and Django Admin but not in shell commands. I have this:

##### Validator

```
def validate_cuit(value):
    """ Must be exactly 11 numeric characters """
    if len(value) != 11:
        raise CuitValidationException('CUIT should have 11 characters')

    if not value.isdigit():
        raise CuitValidationException('CUIT should only contain numeric characters')

    return value
```

##### Exception

```
class CuitValidationException(ValidationError):
    pass
```

#### Model

```
class Empresa(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, validators=[validate_name])
    cuit = models.CharField(max_length=11, validators=[validate_cuit])
```

If I do this, I get no error

```
e = Empresa.objects.create(name="Testing Case", cuit='1')
```

The only way I found to solve this is by working on the *save* method:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        self.name = validate_name(self.name)
        self.cuit = validate_cuit(self.cuit)
        return super().save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

But I'm sure it shouldn't be neccesary, can you help me with this?

Comment: Django does not run the validators when saving the item, only the `ModelForm`s do, likely for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I'm sure it shouldn't be neccesary, can you help me with this?

Django does not run the validators when saving the item, only the `ModelForm`s do, likely for performance reasons.

Indeed, you can run the validators explicitly with the [**`.full_clean()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean):

```
e = Empresa(name="Testing Case", cuit='1')
e.full_clean()  # will raise error
e.save()
```